# Django - Form Validation Error not showing on Boolean Field

Tags: python, html, django

Not sure why, but no form validation error is showing on the below code.

The form (when the condition of the error is met) doesn't save (which is fine), but there is not validation message on the form?

## FORM

```
   def clean_p45_boolean(self):
        p45_boolean = self.cleaned_data['p45_boolean']
        if p45_boolean == False:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("Please attach your latest P45."))
        return p45_boolean
```

## TEMPLATE

I've included both errors and nonfield errors

```
            <!-- Error -->
            <div class="field">
                {% for error in employment_employee_form.p45_boolean.errors %}
                    <p class="help is-danger">
                        {{error}}
                    </p>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>

            <!-- Non Field Errors -->
            <div class="field">
            {% if employment_employee_form.non_field_errors %}
                <p class="help is-danger">
                    {{employment_employee_form.non_field_errors}}
                </p>
            {% endif %}
            </div>
```

## MODEL

```
# U.K. EMPLOYEE PAYE MODEL

class UK_Employee_PAYE(models.Model):

    p45_boolean = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Do not have a P45?', blank=False, default=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `required=False` in Django form boolean field. [Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/fields/#booleanfield)

```
p45_boolean = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

Comment: But if I've put blank=False, isn't that the same as required = True?

Comment: The guidance also says: if you want to include a boolean in your form that can be either True or False (e.g. a checked or unchecked checkbox), you must remember to pass in required=False when creating the BooleanField. It could be either ticked or unticked, so shouldn't required = False. Also isn't required set to True by default anyway?

Comment: `blank=False` will determine the field is not left blank on the form. But if the checkbox isn't checked, browsers do not send the field in the POST parameters of requests. So if it is not in the views.py the condition doesn't match. Whereas `required=True` does what we want here.

Comment: The problem is, that the checkbox can be blank. My validation check is, if checkbox is blank, AND other field is blank, then give a validation error. So, my validation function won't even check if the checkbox is blank (as when you set required = True, the form then won't even submit)

Comment: I think I know why this is happening. It is something in the view.py. It is returning an unbound form (which won't have the validation error passed with it)

Comment: If this is the case, check your views.py, However knowing your exact requirements I have edited the response. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Your answer deals with a model field, but a model field has no `required=...` parameter.

Comment: I deleted the 'required = #' option. It wasn't needed. I left blank = false, and default = false. In the view, it was correctly not saving the form, but went down a branch where it 'redirected' to back to the same page (as if the form was valid... - my view logic tries to handle several forms...). Instead, for that form, it should have gone down a branch where it re-re-rended the template with the bound form (that would have had the validation error in it). So, its all fixed now. I initially thought the error was in the template, or form.py, or possibly model.py, but it was in the view.py

Comment: @ Willem Van Onsem, my mistake, but unintentional. Noted.